# How to get errorstream using HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode() and HttpURLConnection.getErrorStream()?

Tags: java, http, web

when I only use HttpURLConnection.getErrorStream(),I can not get errstream.But when I use  HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode()  before HttpURLConnection.getErrorStream(),then I can get    errorstream.
like this ,I can get errorstream:

```
if(urlconn.getResponseCode()>=400){
    is = urlconn.getErrorStream();
    System.out.println("error!!!");
    }else{
    is=urlconn.getInputStream();
    }
```

like this ,I can not get errorstream,'is' is null:

```
is = urlconn.getErrorStream();
```

Comment: I agree, and so does the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream()). Your question?

Comment: like this is also  can get errorstream:               urlconn.getResponseCode();                                         urlconn.getErrorStream();

Comment: Again I agree, and again I am unable to discern a question here. Have you read the Javadoc?

Comment: Thank you! And I want to kow Why does this happen. getResponseCode() and getErrorStream() how to work.And Why before get errorstream ,we shoud user "getResponseCode()" firstly!

Comment: Because that's what it says in the Javadoc. If you want to know why the class was written that way, you're asking in the wrong place.

Comment: @BigJnoe https://stackoverflow.com/a/23593555/1599699