# Java HttpURLConnection.getInputStream but get 401 IOException

Tags: java, httpresponse, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-401

I am writing a REST client for CouchDB in Java. The following code should be quite standard:

```
    this.httpCnt.connect();
    Map<String, String> responseHeaders = new HashMap<>();
    int i = 1;
    while (true){
        String headerKey = this.httpCnt.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
        if (headerKey == null)
            break;
        responseHeaders.put(headerKey, this.httpCnt.getHeaderField(i));
        i++;
    }
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(this.httpCnt.getInputStream());
    StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    while(true){
        int noCharRead = reader.read(buffer);
        if (noCharRead == -1){
            reader.close();
            break;
        }
        responseBuilder.append(buffer, 0, noCharRead);
    }
```

I want to test what happen if the authentication fails. However if the authentication fails, when calling `getInputStream` of the HttpURLConnection, I get directly an IOException saying the server responses 401. I suppose if the server responses something, no matter success or failure, it should be able to read whatever the server returns. And I am sure in this case the server does return some text in the body, since if I do a `GET` to the server using curl and the authentication fails, I get a JSON object as the response body with some error messages in it.

Is there any way to still get the response body even if 401?

Comment: You could repalce the `while` with `for` loops to make the code more readable

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633048/httpurlconnection-reading-response-content-on-403-error):

"The [HttpURLConnection.getErrorStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream%28%29) method will return an InputStream which can be used to retrieve data from error conditions (such as a 404), according to the javadocs."

Answer (score 26):

You need to check for the http status using `getResponseCode()` to decide if you should use `getInputStream()` or `getErrorStream()`. In this case, you need to read the error stream.

Comment: Thanks! I would accept your reply as answer, but there can be only one answer possible...

Comment: OK, given the error code, how do you then decide which stream to use?